# Issue with second monitor on Ubuntu 18.04 startup

Tags: 18.04, display, display-resolution, steam, hardware

I'm using a notebook with a second display connected with a VGA cable and I have Ubuntu 18.04.

I've never faced any issue before but after I started to play Age of Empires 2 HD (using Steam + protontricks) with full screen on my built-in display, the problems showed up. When I rebooted my computer, the second display didn't show anything.

So I went to Display settings, selected "Join Displays" options. The second monitor turned on for just a few seconds and then turned off right away. After some tweaks on Display settings, somehow the second monitor finally remained turned on, but it was a random behaviour.

I ran `xrandr --listmonitors` and this was the output:

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*LVDS-1 1280/344x720/193+0+0  LVDS-1
 1: +VGA-1 1280/373x720/209+0+0  VGA-1
```

And after running `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I suspect that it has something to do with my integrated graphics card, I believe it has messed up after I started to play that game on full resolution.

Do you know why my second monitor is not displaying anything?

Comment: It could be as simple as the VGA cable is going bad.  The monitor and the computer cannot communicate well enough.

Comment: It could be but is kinda strange that it began to happen after playing a video game with full resolution. I'm gonna try with another VGA cable though

Comment: This still doesn't work, any more ideas?

Comment: Please tell us all what graphics card you have.  sudo lshw and let us know what Graphics card you have. You can try the PPA for Nvidia if that is what you have. https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic  You can try rolling back to an older driver?  You can try the Nouveau drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated the post with the output of that command! I have an Intel integrated graphics card. I will try rolling back to an older driver as you say or using Nouveau drivers.

Comment: Hi again. @walttheboss using Noveau Drivers didn't solve my problem, so I'm sure that the only way to fix my issues will be by rolling back to an older driver. How can I do that? Should I boot with an older kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure you know what driver is installed.  You can do this from the GUI or from the command line.

```
nvidia-settings --version
```

Then you can change what version you are using by seeing what is available

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

And then installing the one you want.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-theNumberYouWant
```

Sometimes a purge is recommended before you start.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia-*
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have an external graphics cards, I have an internal graphics cards. I tried by reinstallig xserver-xorg-video-intel but it didn't make any effect. Should I boot with an old Kernel?

Comment: I just found out my external monitor is not completely black, its brightness is too low but I wasn't able to improve it